# SSAS - Attribute Relationships in Natural Hierarchy

Tags: sql, attributes, ssas, hierarchy, relationship

I am finding it difficult to properly comprehend the best use case scenarios for implementing attribute relationships between dimension attributes within SQL Server Analysis Services 2008 R2.

From what I have read, it appears **"Unnatural Hierarchies"** are to be avoided for performance reasons and **"Natural"** Hierarchies are the preferred user-defined Hierarchies.

Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2131988

This being said, I would like to ask your thoughts on the following scenario:

I have a dimension with the following attributes:

---

**Dimension Name:** DimReserveData 
**Dimension Members:**

Program Line 
Coverage Code 
Coverage Type 
Coverage Status

---

I would like to place these attributes within a Hierarchy as shown below in the same order:

**ReserveDataHierarchy** 

........................................ 
Program Line 
Coverage Code 
Coverage Type 
Coverage Status 
........................................

**Hierarchy Info:**

Program Line is a code representing the insurance coverage program that is offered. (ex: AA-23, BB-25, CC-78 ect.)

The coverage code attribute represents a numerical code representing a specific coverage that is offered for a particular program line. (ex: 123, 456 ect.)

Coverage type represents the type of coverage tied to a particular coverage code. (ex: Vehicular or Bodily).

Coverage Status represents the status of a given coverage (Open or Closed).

So, we can say the following regarding cardinality within the Hierarchy:

One program line can contain many coverage codes. 
One coverage code can contain many types. 
One coverage type can contain many status values.

Hence, browsing the Hierarchy will yield the following attributes and corresponding members:

**DimReserveData** 

....................................................................................................*................................. 
**Program Line | Coverage Code | Coverage Type | Coverage Status**
......................................................................................................................................  
AA-12 .................123....................Vehicular................Open 
BB-14 .................456....................Vehicular.................Closed 
CC-23 .................123 ...................Vehicular.................Open 
DD-23 .................456....................Bodily......................Open

My question would be if it would be good practice to model these attributes within a "Natural" or "Unnatural" hierarchy.  I would like to use a "Natural" hierarchy in order to improve performance.

Obviously modeling this hierarchy as a "natural" would require the use of attribute relationships.

Back to my example hierarchy above, would a "Natural" hierarchy be possible if one given Coverage Code attribute belongs to multiple Program Lines as well as multiple Coverage Codes containing the same Coverage Type?

In this helpful post: http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/idiots-guide-to-ssas-attribute-relationships/ it is mentioned that in the scenario where one city belongs to multiple states or provinces, one can modify the attribute key columns so that each attribute within the hierarchy is uniquely defined.

Would this work in my example above?

I am thinking that I could model the attribute relationships like so: (using SSAS 2008 R2)

[Surrogate Key Attribute from Dimension] -- > Coverage Status -- > Coverage Type -- > Coverage Code -- > Program Line

Each attribute above would have its key columns set like so:

.................................... 
**Coverage Status:** 

.................................... 
Coverage Status 
Coverage Type

.................................... 
**Coverage Type:** 

.................................... 
Coverage Type 
Coverage Code

.................................... 
**Coverage Code:** 

.................................... 
Coverage Code 
Program Line

.................................... 
Program Line:
.................................... 
Program Line

Would this work?  Is this scenario better suited for an **"Unnatural"** hierarchy?

I greatly appreciate your time reading my post above!

Thanks!

Comment: Coverage Status might need to be defined as the combination of Program line, coverage code, coverage type and coverage status. Coverage type based on Program line, coverage code, coverage type.

Answer (score 1):

If you MUST have these in a hierarchy, force it to be a natural one.  You'll pay a less severe performance penalty, than just using an unnatural hierarchy.  The penalty with a forced-natural hierarchy is primarily related to an increase in key-size (since you'll use composite keys to naturalize the hierarchy).

But perhaps you should think about what it is you are trying to achieve by forcing these attributes into a user-hierarchy?

Is it to simplify some MDX queries?
Is the dimension too wide (too many attributes directly related to the key) and causing memory pressure during processing?

If the answer is simply to group these attributes for the user-interface (ex. Excel), you might want to consider simply going with a naming convention that allows these attributes to appear in the order you prefer...

Comment: Thank you iPolvo, this makes total sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft deleted that KB that you referenced (Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2131988)

I am really frustrated with whoever is managing KB content over there.  Someone needs to take their finger off the DEL key!  That was my KB and I probably spent over a week of my life helping MS document the unexpected problems in unnatural hierarchies (vs equivalent cross-join of attributes)!!!